# Error 3033: Prblm in mapping fragments: EntitySets 'Entity1' and 'Entity2' are both mapped to table 'Addresses'. Their primary keys may collide

Tags: entity-framework

Context. I want to separate a shipping table into two tables, the first one for general data about the shipping that are most frequently used and in the second table to store the pickup and destination addresses in different records with a selector field RecordType, in order to retrieve the addresses information only when is required. For that purpose, I created three entities, the entity Move for the shipping general information, the entity pick up address and the entity destination address, the last two entities have an additional field "address type" to distinguish which is pickup and which is destination.
With the mapping details screen in the model I mapped both entities, the PickupAddress, and DestinationAddress to the same table MoveAddresses, PickupAddress with codition recordtype =”P” and DestinationAddress with condition recordtype = “D”.
When I rebuild the datalayer solution I got the following errors

```
Error   2   Error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 625: Condition member 'MoveAddresses.AddressType' with a condition other than 'IsNull=False' is mapped. Either remove the condition on DestinationAddresses.AddressType or remove it from the mapping.

Error   4   Error 3033: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 647: EntitySets 'PickupAddresses' and 'DestinationAddresses' are both mapped to table 'MoveAddresses'. Their primary keys may collide.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to implement is Table per Hierarchy.  From your description, it sounds like you are using the Entity Framework Designer surface.  To model Table per Hiearchy in the Entity Framework Designer is a multiple step process.

1. Create an Entity which represents the Table which will hold the multiple bound entities (in your case, create an `Address` entity with `Addresses` entity set, matching the entire Addresses Table).  Forget about the `Move` Table for the moment, you only care at the moment about the table sharing data.
2. Right click the designer surface, Add -> Entity, set the Base type of each Derived entry to `Address` i.e. `PickupAddress` Derived from `Address`
3. Cut and paste any specific entries that belong to each derived entity, removing them from the base entity and pasting them into the derived entity.  i.e. `pickup date` moved from `Address` to `PickupAddress`.
4. Delete the Descriminator property from the base entity.  it isn't actually a property which can be used directly by the entities.
5. Right click each derived entity, choose table mapping.  choose the base table for the mapping, and set the discriminator values.
6. Now you are ready to create entity relationships between your derived classes and your other table as necessary.